# A fair coin is tossed four times

Tags: probability, self-study

A fair coin is flipped 4 times, what is the probability of obtaining at least one head in the first two tosses?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the coin is fair, the first two tosses can be TT, TH, HT, or HH with equal probability for each pair. The last three pairs (three of the four) match your desired first two flips, and the last two flips do not matter because each pair can have the same last two flips. So the probability of obtaining at least one head in the first two of four tosses is $3/4$.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info (or do you think this is not such a question?)

Comment: Also, if a fair coin had been tossed and landed heads four times in a row, the odds of getting a heads in the next two flips is still $3/4$.  The preceding flips don't matter either.

Comment: I agree that the question should be tagged as self-study.